# My Engine flickers when I try to render 2D and 3D

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, buffer, lwjgl

I am working with LWJGL to make a game. It's very basic. Before even implementing any sort of gpu rendering, or fancy model loaders, I wanted to make sure I could at least render 2D and 3D at the same time; My game has a gui while you walk around. Or at least, it is supposed to. Here is my initialization code; The flickering does not happen when I only render 3D.

```
public void clearGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

public void init3D() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective((float) 68, Engine.size[0] / Engine.size[1], 0.3f, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);


}

public void render3D(Camera c) {

    init3D();
    clearGL();

    //Do translations here
    glTranslatef(0f, -5f, 0f);


    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-50f, 0f, -50f);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(50f, 0f, -50f);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(50f, 0f, 50f);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-50f, 0f, 50f);
    glEnd();


}

public void init2D() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Engine.size[0], 0, Engine.size[1], -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glLoadIdentity();


}

public void render2D() {
    init2D();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0f, 50f);
    glVertex2f(50f, 50f);
    glVertex2f(50f, 0f);
    glVertex2f(0f, 0f);

    glPopMatrix();

}
```

I can tell its rendering at all because I am drawing a quad to represent the floor in JBullet. For some reason it is above the cameras head, but when I translate the camera up towards it it get's further away, which is why I translated the Camera to -5. That's another problem, for another day.

Answer (score 0):

You should ***really*** consider disabling the depth test when you "switch" from 3D to 2D if you are going to draw at **Z=0** (middle of your depth range). Half of the visible space in your 3D scene will potentially obstruct your 2D drawing if you do not do this. Alternatively, you could replace your `glVertex2f (...)` calls with `glVertex3f (x,y, -1.0)` to bring everything in 2D to the very front of the depth range.

But the really weird thing about all of this is the end of your `render2D (...)` function: You never call `glEnd (...)` and you pop a matrix that you appear never to have pushed.  That is two sources of mismatched weirdness, either one of them could be causing your problem.

Comment: OP should also call glClearDepth(1).

Comment: Why? That would be completely redundant, as they already did that in `init3D (...)`. Not to mention, that is the default value to begin with.

Comment: Nevermind, didn't see that. Does the depth bit not change when rendering in 2D though? Should he not clear it?

Comment: It probably would not hurt to clear the depth buffer, but it definitely is not necessary. Since this is orhographic 2D and all of those vertices are at the same Z value the quads will all generate the same depth value - if **Z=-1** is used, then the quads will ***always*** pass the depth test given the current setup. Unfortunately that is not currently how the code is working - it is drawing at **Z=0**, which is the exact middle of the depth buffer in this particular setup, and may be covered up by any 3D objects in the scene.